# Wordpress get_terms don't work when hide_empty is set to true

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I try to get only custom taxonomy (with posts), e.g. portfolio_category.
Code:

```
$args = array(
        'orderby'       => 'name',
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'    => true,
        'fields'        => 'id=>name',
        'get'           => 'all',
);
$TermsList = \get_terms($tax_name, $args);
```

But if I set hide_empty to true or remove 'get' => 'all' it always return empty array.

Comment: That means you don't have any portfolio post tagged with your taxo terms. Fill some of your portofolio posts then try again.

Comment: @Tiki-Web I have posts in some portfolio categories. The problem is in:  'fields' => 'id=>name' when I change this line to 'fields' => 'all' everything is OK. Buy I need only id and name.

Comment: According to the [doc](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) you don't need to set `get` and `hide_empty` parameters, as you use default values. Maybe you have a conflict between `get` and `hide_empty`. Just to be sure, can you try discarding these params ? I'm using the same code to build my own porftolio categories list, and it works perfectly provided there are published posts in at least 1 category.